# Can a constructor be injected into a class and how?

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-aop

Suppose I have a base class (which i'm simplifying):

```
public class GenericException extends Exception {
    private Map<String,Object> map;
    //...
    public GenericException(String message, String[] params, Object... values) {
        super(message);
        map = createMap(params, values);        
    }
    //... other stuff
    public String getType() {
        getClass().getName();
    }
}
```

This class may be extended by clients but there is no point in adding members to any of its sub-classes, because the class and its sub-classes, when thrown, will result in some Json streamed to some client, containing only the map, the type, and the message

A typical sub-class may be something like

```
public class Exception1 extends GenericException {
    private String message = "something";
    private String params = new String[] {"foo", "bar"};
    //...
    public Exception1(Object... values) {
        super(message, params, values);
    }
    //... other stuff
}
```

At some other point in the code there is a need to take the Json representation of any GenericException (or its sub-class) and create an instance of that class. The type attribute may be used to figure out which class needs to be instantiated, and the map is in the Json representation so the params and values can be obtained.
If every sub-class could be forced to implement a constructor having the parameters

```
String message, String[] params, Object... values
```

then it would be easy.
But every sub-classs, although eventually it must call the constructor in GenericException, may have various unknown constructors.

I'm looking for some magic that would allow me to inject such a [virtual] constructor into every sub-class of GenericException, 
so that the code that needs to create the exeption from Json
can call this "virtual" constructor perhaps by reflection...

Is it possible to create this magic by somehow annotating the class and doing some Spring Aspect annotation? (Spring is used in this project))

Or is there some other way to do it?

Additional information added 10/16/2018
Thanks to all the commenters. I guess I need to add more information:
1) I'm using Spring Boot
2) i don't want to add setters. I think exceptions should be immutable. Let's not argue about that.
3) sure there could be directive that you must implement some additional constructor in every extension of the base class. But i prefer not to do that.
4) I know I need to use AspectJ. But how is that done?

So think about it this way: people are writing sub-classes of GenericExceptions and i don't have any control over their code. I own GenericException and i am responsibile for some infrastructure code which is supposed to reconstruct any sub-class of GenericExceptions which is in the classpath but does not have any setters.

Comment: Feels like this would be a lot easier just using a custom JSON deserializer.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  What is wrong with a non-magical call to a super constructor from your `constructor` ?  Looks like you are already doing it `super(message, params, values);`  - why is no good?

Comment: why do you want a constructor? I assume when you create a child instance you want to populate `map` values in your parent exception. is that correct ?

Comment: I'm afraid, this is not possible in Java. Normally, you add a non-args constructor and let the demarshalling set the values using setters. Otherwise, I fear you'll have to resort to a JSON deserializer.